# Airflow - DAG integrity tests - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable

Tags: pytest, airflow

I am currently writing some airflow DAG integrity tests for the first time. I am coming across an error where some of my operators/tasks are referencing airflow variables, eg:

```
test_var= Variable.get("AIRFLOW_VAR_TEST_VAR")
```

When i run a integrity test using pytest, i get the below error:

**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable**

I can work around this by replacing the Variable.get code with a hard-coded value, but wondering if there is a better way to deal with this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run

`AIRFLOW__CORE__UNIT_TEST_MODE=True airflow db reset`

This will initialise and re-create unit test sqlite database from scratch.

Alternatively you can run pytest with the airflow-specific switch `--with-db-init` switch which does the same.

Comment: I tried the alternative, but I'm getting `pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --with-db-init` , is something extra needed for this?

Comment: This needs airlfow sources and conftest.py from Airflow available in your `tests` folder.
 https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/25a50bb1fbf0e228706c7927cb36570921881adb/tests/conftest.py#L116

Comment: Generally speaking it works in `breeze` environment of Airlfow out-of-the box.

Comment: In my case, we don't have the unit test mode enabled so just `airflow db reset` was sufficient for me 